# Why $\int_{E} g(x|y) dx$ is Borel-measurable for any $E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(X, Y)$ be a random variable with an absolutely continuous distribution function given by probability density function $f$. Let $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ be the marginal probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. We show that for any $E \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
$$ P(X \in E \mid Y=y )=\int_{E}\frac{f(x, y)}{f_2(y)} dx \quad\text {a.s. }\left(P_{Y}(y)\right),$$

that is, $\int_{E} g(x|y) dx$, where $g(x|y)=f(x, y) / f_{2}(y)$, is a version of
$P(X \in E | Y=y).$
First note that $g(x|y)$ is defined only for $f_{2}(y) \neq 0$, but this set has probability $0$.

Clearly ${\color{DarkRed} {\int_{E} g(x|y) dx} }$
${\color{DarkRed} {\text{is Borel-measurable for any}} }$  ${\color{DarkRed} {E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).} }$ .........

---

I don't know why $\int_{E} g(x|y) dx$ is Borel-measurable for any $E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})?$

I'm not sure if my following approach is correct.

Let's define $\tilde{g}(x|y):=\begin{cases}
 \frac{f(x,y)}{f_2(y)}& \text{ if } f_2(y)>0 \\
\quad 0 & \text{ if }  f_2(y)=0 
\end{cases}.$

Since the density function $f$ is a $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $f_1(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dy,f_2(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dx$ and $\tilde{g}(x|y)$ are $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable functions.

For any fixed $E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$,  $\chi_{E}(x)\cdot \tilde{g}(x|y)$ is a $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. By *Tonelli's Theorem*,
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{E}(x)\cdot \tilde{g}(x|y)dx=\int_{E}\tilde{g}(x|y)dx$ is a $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function.

Next,I only get  $\int_{E} g(x|y) dx=\int_{E} \tilde{g}(x|y) dx \quad \text {a.s.}\left(P_{Y}(y)\right) $ for any fixed $E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e.  $\int_{E} g(x|y) dx$ is  almost surely of  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function on  $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),P_Y\right)$ for any fixed $E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$ But why the author said $\int_{E} g(x|y) dx$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable for any $E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})?$
Any help you can provide would be welcomed.

Comment: I guess the author was a bit sloppy when describing the definition of $g(x|y)$. The map $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{f(x,y)}{f_2(y)}$ is *a priori* only defined on the set $\{(x,y):f_2(y)\neq0\}$. So, I am sure that the author actually intended $g(x|y)$ to be any suitable choice of Borel-measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that agrees with $f(x,y)/f_2(y)$ whenever $f_2(y)\neq 0$. Such a function surely exists, as your $\tilde{g}(x|y)$ is one such example and you essentially proved what the author has claimed.